# Syncfusion datagrid onclick selected row?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, syncfusion

Is there a demo (with source) of a datagrid that when we click on a selected row, it opens the details razer page of the selected row?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `OnRecordClick` parameter. Information can be found here: https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/datagrid/events#rowselecting

```
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Grids

<SfGrid DataSource="@Orders">
    <GridEditSettings AllowAdding="true" AllowEditing="true" AllowDeleting="true" Mode="EditMode.Normal"></GridEditSettings>
    <GridEvents OnRecordClick="RecordClickHandler" TValue="Order"></GridEvents>
    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.OrderID) HeaderText="Order ID" IsPrimaryKey="true" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.CustomerID) HeaderText="Customer Name" Width="150"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.OrderDate) HeaderText=" Order Date" Format="d" Type="ColumnType.Date" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="130"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(Order.Freight) HeaderText="Freight" Format="C2" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120"></GridColumn>
    </GridColumns>
</SfGrid>

@code{
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Orders = Enumerable.Range(1, 75).Select(x => new Order()
        {
            OrderID = 1000 + x,
            CustomerID = (new string[] { "ALFKI", "ANANTR", "ANTON", "BLONP", "BOLID" })[new Random().Next(5)],
            Freight = 2.1 * x,
            OrderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-x),
        }).ToList();
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public int? OrderID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
        public double? Freight { get; set; }
    }

    public void RecordClickHandler(RecordClickEventArgs<Order> args)
    {
        // Here, you can customize your code.
    }
}
```